# Does Visual Studio Premium include the App Store API?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

Rephrasing the question if not clear:

Is Express for Windows 8 the only software to design Metro apps with?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Store apps are supported in all the versions of Visual Studio.  I am using VS Ultimate to dev Windows Store apps as I type this.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) Express though has a separate Windows 8 version.